# Python subprocess.call doesn't work without shell=True

Tags: python, shell

I'm using Python to call `cscope` internally. For this I'm using `subprocess.call`.

The problem is that it's not working without `shell=True`

The following code works as expected:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("cscope -d -L0'temp'", shell=True)
```

But the following doesn't, it returns with `0` status code, but there is no output

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["cscope", "-d", "-L0'temp'"])
```

Any ideas as to why the above is happening?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No error. Just that the command doesn't work.

Comment: There *has* to be some kind of error; try setting ``stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT`` and check the process's output.

Comment: I used `call(["cscope", "-d", "-L0'temp'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,  stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`. Still no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the arguments, the args are passed directly to the process without using the shell when shell=False:

```
subprocess.call(["cscope", "-d", "-L0","temp"])
```

You should use check_call:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(["cscope", "-d", "-L0", "temp"])
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. Although why doesn't the one in my question work?

Comment: Whilst this is *most likely* the cause and solutino; I was hoping the OP would demonstrate the error that not properly specifying arguments would show :)

Comment: @KartikAnand Please see my comment above; ``cscope`` will be throwing some kind of error that you are silently ignoring.

Comment: Let me check for that!

Comment: `check_call` is returning 0 for `check_call(["cscope", "-d", "-L0'temp'"])`

Comment: @KartikAnand. There is a zero exit status running the code it just does not do what you want when you quote the arguments with shell=False, I mean in general to use `check_call` unless you really don't care about the exit status

Comment: Yeah, but why isn't it working with `shell=False`. I thought `check_call` would print some error because of which it's not working.

Comment: Because the args are passed directly to the process without using the shell

Comment: But if I do `cscope -d -L0'temp'` it works well on the commandline. They why does passing `"-L0'temp'"` have a problem?